# Prove that $\lim\limits_{N\to M-}\int_0^1 \frac{N}{\sqrt{F(Nt)-F(N)}} \mathrm{d} t = +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

> $\newcommand\d{\mathrm{d}\,}$
> Let $f(x) = -x + \frac{1}{8}\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ and $F(x)$ be its primitive,
> i.e.,
> $$ F(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{8}\bigl((1+x)\ln(1+x) + (1-x)\ln(1-x)\bigr).$$
> Let $M>0$ be the unique positive zero point of $f(x)$. What I want to prove is
> $$ \lim_{N\to M-}g(N):=
>   \lim_{N\to M-}\int_0^1 \frac{N}{\sqrt{F(Nt)-F(N)}} \d t = +\infty. $$

My attempt:

Let $\phi(x) = (1+x)\ln(1+x) + (1-x)\ln(1-x)$. Since $\phi$ is convex, we have
$$\phi(N) - \phi(Nt) \geq \phi'(Nt)N(1-t) = N(1-t)\ln\frac{1+Nt}{1-Nt}.$$
So
$$ F(Nt) - F(N) \leq \frac12 N^2(1-t^2) + \frac18 N(t-1)\ln\frac{1+Nt}{1-Nt}.$$
Hence
$$ g(N) \geq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{
  \sqrt{\frac12(1-t^2) + \frac{t-1}{8N}\ln\frac{1+Nt}{1-Nt}}} \d t.$$
Let
$$\delta = -Nt + \frac{1}{8}\ln\frac{1+Nt}{1-Nt}\to 0\quad
  \text{as}\ t\to 1-\ \text{and}\ N\to M-$$
since $M$ is the zero point of $f(x)$. Then
\begin{align*}
  g(N)
  & \geq \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{(1-t^2) + 2(t-1)\bigl(\frac{\delta}{N}+t\bigr)}} \d t \\
  & = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\bigl(t+\frac{\delta}{N}-1\bigr)^2 - 
      \bigl(\frac{\delta}{N}\bigr)^2}} \d t \\
  & \geq \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{2}}{-t-\frac{\delta}{N}+1} \d t.
\end{align*}
If $\delta$ doesn't depend on $t$, we can compute the last integration directly.
However, it does. I need some suggestions on how to modify my process to make it work or
another method is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fact 1**: It holds that, for all $N \in (0, M]$ and $t \in [0, 1]$
$$F(Nt) - F(N) \le - f(N) N (1 - t)
+ \frac{N^2(4N^2 - 3)}{8(1 - N^2)}(1 - t)^2. $$
(The proof is given at the end.)

Using Fact 1, we have, for all $9/10 < N < M$,
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^{N/M} \frac{N}{\sqrt{F(Nt) - F(N)}}\,\mathrm{d} t \\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \int_0^{N/M} \frac{N}{\sqrt{- f(N) N (1 - t)
   + \frac{N^2(4N^2 - 3)}{8(1 - N^2)}(1 - t)^2}}\,\mathrm{d} t\\[6pt]
 ={}& \int_0^{N/M} \frac{N}{(1 - t)\sqrt{\frac{- f(N) N}{1-t}
   + \frac{N^2(4N^2 - 3)}{8(1 - N^2)}}}\,\mathrm{d} t \\
 \ge{}& \int_0^{N/M} \frac{N}{(1 - t)\sqrt{\frac{- f(N) N}{1-\frac{N}{M}}
   + \frac{N^2(4N^2 - 3)}{8(1 - N^2)}}}\,\mathrm{d} t\\[6pt]
 ={}& - \ln\left(1 - \frac{N}{M}\right)\cdot\frac{N}{\sqrt{\frac{- f(N) N}{1-\frac{N}{M}}
   + \frac{N^2(4N^2 - 3)}{8(1 - N^2)}}} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where we use $f(N) \le 0$ on $(0, M]$.

By L'Hopital's rule, we have
$$\lim_{N \to M^{-}} \frac{f(N)}{1- \frac{N}{M}} = - \frac{M(4M^2 - 3)}{4(1 - M^2)}. \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), we are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

Let
$$g(t) := - f(N) N (1 - t)
+ \frac{N^2(4N^2 - 3)}{8(1 - N^2)}(1 - t)^2
- [F(Nt) - F(N)].$$

We have
$$g''(t) = \frac{N^4(1 - t^2)}{4(1 - N^2)(1 - N^2t^2)} \ge 0.$$
Thus, $g(t)$ is convex on $[0, 1]$.

Also, $g'(1) = 0$.
Thus, $g(t) \ge g(1) = 0$ for all $t\in [0, 1]$.

We are done.

Comment: Amazing! How can you think of constructing such a function $g(t)$?@River Li

Comment: Oh, I know. It's the first 2 order Taylor expansion of function $F(Nt)-F(N)$ at $t=1$.

Comment: @Stephen Yes, it is.